# Magento Pager $this-getPages array empty

Tags: php, magento, pager, magento-1.8

I just upgraded my magento site from the rather ancient 1.3 to 1.8. The pager for my product list has malfunctioned. I've verified that the urls themselves work by adding the query string variables manually.

I think I've traced where the problem is but I'm at a loss of how to remedy this. In the pager loop there is the line:

```
            <?php foreach ($this->getPages() as $_page): ?>
```

However $this->getPages() is not returning an array.  Any idea where the issue could be and how to patch?

Comment: What is it returning?  What's the URL you're looking at?

Comment: The website url is: http://www.aeroartinc.com/st-petersburg-collection.html

Comment: The url http://www.aeroartinc.com/st-petersburg-collection.html?p=2 does work but the pagination toolbar is failing. I've traced the issue to getPages returning a completely empty array in the pager.phtml / toolbar.phtml.